default session expiry issue on Rails
I have an application running in production mode. After a while, the session data seems to clear out. Currently I am using vanilla Rails 7.1.1.
What could be causing this? I want session data to stick around as long as possible.

By default Rails issues the session cookies with no expiry. Cookies with no expiry are removed when the browser window is closed. Use the inspector in your browser to look at the set-cookie headers.

This would set the session cookie to expire automatically 14 days after creation.
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 14.days

You can check the documentation
